# How do you customize the d3 link strength as a function of the links and nodes counts ? (d3 v4)

Tags: d3.js, graph, hyperlink, force-layout

I am trying to write my own function to weigh links for a d3 v4 Force directed graph.

The default strength function is given [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/link.js#L22) and according to the [readme](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_strength) it is possible to change it by passing a new function as an argument. (Note that the function in the readme is slightly different than the one in the actual code).

This is the part of the code I would like to work :

```
 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink()
                    .distance(60)
                    .id(function (d) { return d.name;})
                    .strength( function (link) {/* my code here */}))
```

I have tried replacing the comment with the default :

```
function (link) { return 1 / Math.min(count[link.source.index],
                                      count[link.target.index]); }
```

Without success.

Comment: `count` is not accessible from within the callback provided to `.strength()`. This variable is used internally by `d3.forceLink()` but is not exposed. It might help to specify what you want to achieve with your code, to help you find a solution with the means at hand.

Comment: yes, I realized that a bit late... I was able to make it work with `1 / Math.min(d.source.size, d.target.size) ` because my nodes have a `size` attribute which replaces that count. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the example you provided, but you need to pass what links are to the simulations forceLink function. If your example actually succeeds in constructing links you might consider externalising the calculation and then calling that function from inside links: Here is an example that works for me.

```
 var weightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain(d3.extent(edges, function (d) { return d.weight }))
.range([.1, 1])


graph = d3.forceSimulation()
.nodes(nodes)
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
  .strength(-75)  // -1000
  .distanceMax([250]))    
.force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .links(edges)
    .id(function(d) { return d.index })
    .strength (function (d) {return weightScale(d.weight)})
    .distance(55))
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(250, 250)) //  width / 2, height / 2
.on("tick", forceTick);
```

I use a scale `weightScale` on the link weights, which is called inside `.strenght`. 
You can either pass the links like this:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(*YOURLINKS*)
```

or this:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink()
  .links(*YOURLINKS*)
```